# how can i set local notification for last 10 minutes remaining where the count down timer is set using NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had set the countdown timer for 1 hour 40 minutes and i want to set local notification for last 10 minutes and last 5 minutes remaining.

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

   notification.fireDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5400];
    notification.alertBody = @"Some body";

    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

I had tried this but its not working.

Comment: do you care to elaborate your efforts? Show your work please so people don't waste time offering a solution that doesn't fit your scope

Answer (score 0):

You need set the notification fireDate

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    notification.fireDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:*YOUR 1 hour 30 minutes*];
    notification.alertBody = @"Some body";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

and

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    notification.fireDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:*YOUR 1 hour 35 minutes*];
    notification.alertBody = @"Some body";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,i hope, this will help you...

```
//Create Notification here

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = someTime;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your time will expire in 10 mins";
localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

Do same for last five min.

Answer (score 0):

My time period is **60** you can change according to your choice.

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:**60**];

localNotification.alertBody = @"your message you want to show in notification";

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: UILocalNotification is depecrated now can you add for iOS 10 also. That will be great :)